# Sign for applied filter in Kendo UI Grid ColumnMenu

Tags: javascript, asp.net, filter, grid, kendo-ui

Is it possible to point out user attention that some filter from Column Menu filter's was applied at this moment when use a column menu? And keep track on applied filters? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create some HTML element which the user can see and set its content to be the value of the fields from the  object returned from the [**filter**()](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource) method of the dataSource. Also  Update its content each time the **[change](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#change)** event of the dataSource is triggered.

I hope you got the idea.